# Make AMP versions of Angular Site crawlable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, amp-html

I have an Angular site where I dynamically load properties of objects. I create an AMP site for each of those objects. Normally I would have to link to the AMP site from the canonical site. The problem is that the canonical site is not found by the crawler because it's dynamically loaded via Angular. Is it possible to bypass this restriction, like for example putting references to all objects in the index site of the Angular project?

To make it clearer:
index site: mysite.com
detail view of object: mysite.com/#/detail/object1

If I dynamically add the reference to the amp page based on which object is currently shown, the crawler does not find the amp site because the canonical site can't be found either.
Now I'm wondering if I can somehow put all references to all objects' detail views into the index site without having the restrictions of Angular

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your Angular site crawlable, the data that come's back from the server must return all the information the crawler needs (links,tags,data,ect...).
This is because the crawler does not use JS to interpret your site but rather just scans the initial data returned from the server. You Should look up into server-side rendering for angular apps.

[Here is an article](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/angular-server-side-rendering-in-node-with-express-universal-engine-dce21933ddce) about how to achieve this with a Node.js server.

Comment: I'd like to avoid the pre-rendering. What about creating a sitemap with all the amp links?